# Notification icon that looks like 'b' with 3 dots

Tags: notification-icons

[image: Unknown symbol]

Does anyone know what this symbol is in my notification bar? I'm guessing it's from a 3rd party app. Please excuse my poor attempt to recreate it. :)

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! A better attempt would be a screenshot (less guess-work involved). On most devices, screenshots can be made by pressing the power and volume key at the same time for about a second or two.

Comment: 1. Please post a screen capture with the icon. 2. Please post which device you are using, including OS. 3. Please consider that third-party apps also provide their own notification icons. The vague drawing above does not look like any of the current Lollipop system icons. More info, please.

Comment: The next time it shows up execute the command  `adb shell dumpsys notification` and provide us the output afterwards.

Comment: If you're using an Xperia phone please hold power key for 2 seconds and tap on Take screenshot. Please go through all the apps in app manager and try to unmark Show notifications.

Comment: @Firelord It would be very helpful to say where and how can the OP execute this command.

Comment: Apparently OP also posted the same question on [Android Forums](http://androidforums.com/threads/what-is-this-icon-in-notification-panel.951558/), thanks to Google's reverse image search on this unique image.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered by [wickdaman on Android Forums](http://androidforums.com/threads/what-is-this-icon-in-notification-panel.951558/#post-7101431),

> > <sup>MunstersRebel said:
> >
> > It's beam some proggie that works like a virtual loyalty card holder</sup>
>
> It is! To be exact, it's [Beaming Service for Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobeam.barcodeService) which works with this app, [Beep'nGo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobeam.beepngo) (made by the same folks, Mobeam).
>
> So you can use loyalty cards from shops (e.g. Starbucks). Quite a handy app if you ever wanted it and less crap to have in your wallet...